# Can I dual boot Snow Leopard and Lion?

Tags: macos, snow-leopard, startup

I own a Mac Mini 3.1 with Snow Leopard installed. I would like to dual boot with Lion for development purposes.

I have partitioned my hardisk as described in Point (1) in this tutorial

[How to Install Dual Boot Mac OSX Lion and Snow Leopard](http://osxdaily.com/2011/03/12/how-to-install-dual-boot-mac-os-x-10-7-lion-and-10-6-snow-leopard/)

Can I now buy and download Lion from the apple store and then install it on the new partition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to make your own bootable DVD/USB of the Lion installer to do so. This can be made from the AppStore download and is documented well by OSXDaily.

**[Lion USB Installer](http://osxdaily.com/2011/07/08/make-a-bootable-mac-os-x-10-7-lion-installer-from-a-usb-flash-drive/)

[Lion DVD Installer](http://osxdaily.com/2011/06/08/create-burn-bootable-mac-os-x-lion-install-disc/)**

Then hold ALT at system boot (before chime & Apple logo) and select your install volume.

Comment: or install SL on the Lion partition then boot into it and  install Lion directly from the app store on that

Comment: @Mark That's also a viable option, however, it's best practice to do a clean install rather than an upgrade. It takes less time and is less trouble prone.

Comment: why best practice? OSX has always emphasised upgrades

Comment: It takes less time and is less trouble prone (in my experience). It's also the best suited method for OP.

Comment: OSX usually upgrades relatively well and easily. Upgrades are emphasised to provide a better and more coherent user experience. But in general computing terms, best practice for a fresh install of an OS is to fresh install, not upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

Buy and download the Lion needs the Mac AppStore.  So you need to boot with SL first, buy and download the Lion without installation.  Then follow @macaco's answer to have a clean installation.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.
Open the installer in SL and choose the 2nd partition.

Comment: Please describe your answer in more detail. https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer