# Can a Macbook dual boot Snow Leopard and Lion?

Tags: bootcamp, dual-boot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Dual Boot Lion / SL](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/20843/dual-boot-lion-sl)

My Macbook currently has Snow Leopard on it.  I'd like to try Lion as well, but is there a way to make it dual boot either one, perhaps using BootCamp?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it can dual boot, and no, you don't need Boot Camp. Back up your system first, in case anything goes wrong. Create a second partition. When you download Lion, you'll need to download it without installing, then follow [instructions on the web](http://www.macworld.com/article/161069/2011/07/make_a_bootable_lion_installer.html) to create an install DVD or USB drive. Then, run the installer, and select the blank partition as the target for the install. When you boot, hold down option, and you can select which partition you want.

Comment: Or you could follow the instructions [here](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/20843/dual-boot-lion-sl) -- someone else has already asked and answered this question, it appears.