# How can I install both Snow Leopard and Lion on the same machine?

Tags: macos, snow-leopard, mac, dual-boot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I dual boot Snow Leopard and Lion?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/20843/can-i-dual-boot-snow-leopard-and-lion)

I want to install two operating systems in the same mac pro. Is it possible to  install snowLeopard & Lion on the same macPro like snowLeopard & windows XP?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. You need to create a new partition and install the other OS on it. Here's a detailed [tutorial](http://osxdaily.com/2011/03/12/how-to-install-dual-boot-mac-os-x-10-7-lion-and-10-6-snow-leopard/). The basic steps are:

1. Create a new partition using **Disk Utility**.
2. Install the new OS on the new partition.
3. Set default boot partition using **Startup Disks**.
4. Manually select boot partition **at startup holding down the <kbd>⌥</kbd> key**.